# Compare .CSV to a database table to identify existing records or new records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a group of .csv files with each .csv has their own Invoice Number .  I'm in need to compare the Invoice Number in the csv file and compare it to a table and identify if that Invoice Number exists and if it exists update set of fields and if it does not exists insert file into table.  Is there a way to do this in SSIS?

Comment: Use a for each loop container in ssis and iterate through each file by passing the folder path and load the data to the temp table in your database  . After that you can compare the actual table with the temp table data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SSIS Lookup task to determine if the invoice number from the file exists in the DB table.

Send 'Lookup No Match Output' from lookup to an 'OLE DB  Destination' and insert the data.

Send 'Lookup Match Output' from the lookup to an 'OLE DB Command' and perform an update.